# Suggestion of a book on Measure Theory & Integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm interested in comprehending the very basics of Measure Theory & Integration, especially the Lebesgue measure, measurable functions and integration of measurable functions.

Could you recommend some books which offer very simple examples/solved exercises for these topics? I'm having a hard time understanding this part of Real Analysis and I would need some basic explanations for this.

Comment: "A user-friendly introduction to Lebesgue measure and integration" by Gail S. Nelson is a small and short ($\approx 200$ pages) book and contains and explains the basics well.

Comment: [Here](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/measure.pdf) is a free available pdf with exercises.

Comment: Check out Axler's book "Measure, integration and real analysis". Appeared recently but is a real gem.

Comment: @vitamin d +1 for the Dietmar Salamon notes. His recent functional analysis text (written together with Theo Buhler) is also phenomenal in my opinion.

Comment: @lorenzo Thank you, it looks perfect, but do you know if I could find the solutions to exercises somewhere?

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thank you! Do you know whether I can find the solutions to exercises anywhere?

Comment: Lots of these exercises have already been asked on this site, so the standard ones you can find online :)

Comment: @BiancaI. Unfortunately no. The only book that I know of on measure theory that comes with a publicly available solution manual (on the author's website) is "Measures, Integrals and Martingales" by René Schilling, but is more than twice as long as the one I have previously recommended, at $\approx 500$ pages.